# Reshape from long to wide while summing

Tags: r, pivot, aggregate, reshape

I have the following example data

```
rankP amount defaulted
   1  45925         1
   1 369550         1
   1 177975         1
   1 157850         0
   2  30400         1
   2  93950         0
   2 194075         1
   3  30975         0
   3  66775         1
   3 225850         1
```

and I would like to transform the data so that I'll have the amount per-rank, per-defaulted status (0/1). The required output would look like this:

```
rankP   0         1
1     157850    593450
2      93950    224475
3      30975    292625
```

I'm feeling like I'm missing something very simple, and so far I didn't manage to do it using either `table()` or `aggregate()`

What's the way to achieve that?

Comment: sum by `rankP`, `dcast`.

Comment: Another way is with `dcast(df, rankP ~ defaulted, value.var = "amount", fun.aggregate = sum)` of the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(rankP, defaulted) %>% 
  summarize(amount = sum(amount)) %>% 
  spread(defaulted, amount)

#Source: local data table [3 x 3]
#Groups:

#  rankP      0      1
#1     1 157850 593450
#2     2  93950 224475
#3     3  30975 292625
```

As @akrun mentioned,
using `xtabs` simply

```
xtabs(amount~rankP+defaulted, df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dcast` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format.  By specifying the `fun.aggregate` as `sum`, we get the `sum` of the 'value.var' column. grouped by `rankP`

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(df1, rankP~defaulted, value.var='amount', sum)
```

As @MichaelChirico mentioned in the comments, the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5` have also `dcast`, which would be faster.  There are also other options such as reshaping with multiple 'value.var' columns.  Using the current example, the code will be similar except we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' first (`setDT(df1)`).

Comment: If your table is large, you should use the `dcast` from `data.table` as it will be faster.

Comment: Sorry akrun, when I wrote my comment I did not see you already posted a similar solution.

Comment: @SabDeM It's okay.  It happens to me a lot too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::pivot_wider` you can do -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = defaulted, values_from = amount, 
                       values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)

#  rankP    `1`    `0`
#  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     1 593450 157850
#2     2 224475  93950
#3     3 292625  30975
```